# SQL join only one value when dates overlap

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 tables : assignments and expatriates. Assignments have their effective_start_date and effective_end_date. I need to show information about employees assignments and the dates where they have gone to another country (during assignment dates). I have a select statement, that will later load the data into a table. But the table has a constraint that combination of assignment_id, effective_start_date, effective_end_date has to be a unique. And on expatriates table i don't have assignment_id. Therefore i can't seem to join 2 tables properly. I also can't use first_value and distinct, there has to be an another solution.

```
with assignments (assignment_id, person_id, effective_start_date, effective_end_date) as (
   select 148713, 123, date '2015-03-16', date '4712-12-31' from dual union all
   select 13706, 123, date '2015-03-16', date '4712-12-31' from dual union all
   select 13706, 123, date '2015-01-01', date '2015-03-15' from dual
 ),
 expatriates (person_id, date_from, date_to, home_country, host_country, valid_from, valid_to) as (
   select 123, date '2015-03-16', date '2016-04-15', 'TEST', 'TEST', date '2015-03-16', date'2015-04-15' from dual union all
   select 123, date '2015-01-01', date '2015-03-15', 'TEST2', 'TEST2', date '2015-01-01', date'2015-03-15' from dual union all
   select 123, date '2014-04-16', date '2016-06-15', 'TEST1', 'TEST1', date '2015-04-16', date'2016-06-15' from dual
 ) 

select 
    a.assignment_id, 
    a.person_id, 
    a.effective_start_date,
    a.effective_end_date,
    subq.date_from, 
    subq.date_to, 
    subq.home_country, 
    subq.host_country
from expatriates subq, assignments a
where 
    subq.person_id=a.person_id
and subq.valid_from <= a.effective_end_date
and subq.valid_to >= a.effective_start_date
```

Edit: forgot to mention that i can't use OR statement, because the joins i need to make are actually outer joins, and i can't use union all to fix the problem. I used inner joins just for the example.

Edit nr. 2 : still no solution for this?

Comment: What result do you want (for your sample data)? To me it seems that your query is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select 
    a.assignment_id, 
    a.person_id, 
    a.effective_start_date,
    a.effective_end_date,
    subq.date_from, 
    subq.date_to, 
    subq.home_country, 
    subq.host_country
from expatriates subq, assignments a
where 
    subq.person_id=a.person_id
and (
     (subq.valid_from >= a.effective_start_date and subq.valid_from <= a.effective_end_date)
     or
     (subq.valid_to >= a.effective_start_date and subq.valid_to <= a.effective_end_date)
    )
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me, assignment id, effective_start_date and effective_end date combinations aren't unique. And I didnt mention this at first, but i can't use or statement, because the joins i made will actually be outer joins (i just used inner joins just for the example). And i can't use OR statement in an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use De Morgan's laws in combination with BETWEEN...AND to avoid the ORs?

Something like this: Assuming the clause with the OR you want to avoid is this:

```
(
 (subq.valid_from >= a.effective_start_date and subq.valid_from <= a.effective_end_date)
 OR
 (subq.valid_to >= a.effective_start_date and subq.valid_to <= a.effective_end_date)
)
```

Using BETWEEN...AND, this can be written as:

```
(
 (subq.valid_from BETWEEN a.effective_start_date AND a.effective_end_date)
 OR
 (subq.valid_to BETWEEN a.effective_start_date AND a.effective_end_date)
)
```

De Morgan's laws say that `NOT A OR NOT B` is equivalent to `NOT (A AND B)`. So assuming that

1. `NOT A` is `(subq.valid_from BETWEEN a.effective_start_date AND a.effective_end_date)`, and
2. `NOT B` is `(subq.valid_to BETWEEN a.effective_start_date AND a.effective_end_date)`,

it follows that

1. `A` is `(subq.valid_from NOT BETWEEN a.effective_start_date AND a.effective_end_date)` and
2. `B` is `(subq.valid_to NOT BETWEEN a.effective_start_date AND a.effective_end_date)`.

(Please mark the NOTs before the BETWEENs.)

In conjunction with De Morgan's law, the clause can then be written without OR:

```
NOT (
 subq.valid_from 
   NOT BETWEEN a.effective_start_date 
   AND a.effective_end_date 
 AND 
 subq.valid_to 
   NOT BETWEEN a.effective_start_date 
   AND a.effective_end_date
)
```